# Adding "selected" attribute to the selected option in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating my page builder but I have little problem with select box.

**This is how I create a selectbox via jQuery**

```
    var item_opts = '<select>'
        + '<option value="red">Red</option>'
        + '<option value="green">Green</option>'
        + '<option value="blue">Blue</option>'
        + '<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>'
    + '</select>'

$('.items_options').append(item_opts);
```

**And this is how I call it in PHP**

```
<select>
  <?php if ( $pb_item['message_color'] == "red" ) { ?>
    <option selected="selected" value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <?php } elseif ( $pb_item['message_color'] == "green" ) { ?>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <?php } elseif ( $pb_item['message_color'] == "blue" ) { ?>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <?php } ?>                      
</select>
```

Is there some better solution how how to add parametr "selected" to the selected option than I have?

thx for your time and your advices :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is better solution

```
<select>
    <option <? ($pb_item['message_color'] == 'red'?'selected="selected"') ?> value="red">Red</option>
    <option <? ($pb_item['message_color'] == 'green'?'selected="selected"') ?> value="green">Green</option>
    <option <? ($pb_item['message_color'] == 'blue'?'selected="selected"') ?> value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option <? ($pb_item['message_color'] == 'yellow'?'selected="selected"') ?> value="yellow">Yellow</option>                   
</select>
```

even if you can list options via for loop for example:

```
$colors = array('blue', 'red', ..);
foreach($colors as $color) {
    echo "<option ".($pb_item['message_color'] == $color?'selected="selected"')."value='$color'>" . ucwords($color) . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: And yes, there is even a better solution. And psst, we have this on the website already.

Comment: Thx so much :) It deffinately helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Those Who Trouble Understanding Previous Selected Answer by @vlcekmi3 here some other easy & dirty explanation.

```
$colors = array(
    1 => 'blue', 
    2 => 'red', ..); //init your array with key & value

foreach($colors as $key => $color) { // a loop 

    //print <option value="red"
    echo "<option value=".$key; 

    //print selected if your selected value matched -
    //please check before you echo 'selected' add a space before that
    //you will thank me later
    if($pb_item['message_color'] == $color){ echo " selected"; } 

    // close option with print '>'
    echo '>'; 

    // print your color name
    echo $color; 

    //print </option>
    echo "</option>"; 

}
```

what i Explained here is May be a Dirty Way but this code will help you understand how value will be returned to your view.