# get the whole row of the same ID from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysqli, dropdown

Okay I just changed it to $_POST and it's now working. I'm not sure if this is the shortcut method. At least it's working now. You can help me shrink the code if you want to help me. thanks

```
<?php

 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
 or die ('Cannot connect to db');

 $result = $conn->query("select * from english");

 echo "<html>";
 echo "<body>";
 echo "<form method = POST>";
 echo "<select name = 'Students'>";

 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          $LRN = $row['LRN'];
          $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
          $First = $row['First_Name'];
          $Lvl = $row['Level'];
          $Q1 = $row['Q1'];
          $Q2 = $row['Q2'];
          $Q3 = $row['Q3'];
          $Q4 = $row['Q4'];
          $Final = $row['FINAL'];
          echo '<option value="'.$LRN.'|'.$Last.', '.$First.'|'.$Lvl.'|'.$Q1.'|'.$Q2.'|'.$Q3.'|'.$Q4.'|'.     $Final.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

 }

 echo "</select>";
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Show'>";
 echo "</form>";

 $show = $_POST['Students'];
        $show_explode = explode('|', $show);

    echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>". $show_explode[0]."</td><td>". $show_explode[1]."</td><td>". $show_explode[2]."</td><td>". $show_explode[3]."</td><td>". $show_explode[4]."</td><td>". $show_explode[5]."</td><td>". $show_explode[6]."</td><td>". $show_explode[7]."</td></tr>";

 echo "</table>";




 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
 ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to unset variables before you assign them.

Comment: *I want to do is get the whole row of the same id of the drop down menu* requirement or question?

Comment: Don't put all the information in the `<option>` like that. Just put the ID in the option, and then look it up in the database when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put all the details in the option value like that. Just put the ID in the value.

```
echo "<select name = 'Students'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $LRN = $row['LRN'];
    $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
    $First = $row['First_Name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Then look it up in the database when the form is submitted.

```
if (isset($_POST['Students'])) {
    $lrn = $_POST['Students'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Level, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, FINAL FROM english WHERE LRN = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $lrn);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($last, $first, $level, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $final);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>$lrn</td><td>$last, $first</td><td>$level</td><td>$q1</td><td>$q2</td><td>$q3</td><td>$q4</td><td>$final</td></tr></table";
}
```

Comment: well very very thank you!! that makes my codes neat. thanks! Now, lastly, how do I make the dropdown menu remain when I hit submit? it goes back to option 1 after submit button. Thanks again!

Comment: Test if `$LRN == $_POST['Students']`, then add the `selected` attribute to the option.

Comment: In the `while()` loop that adds the options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183945/adding-selected-attribute-to-the-selected-option-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$foreach**  for minimum code when deal with Array. Here code goes

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// after post a form ur code goes here
$show = $_POST['Students']; $show_explode = explode('|', $show);
 echo "<table><tr>
<th>LRN</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Q1</th>
<th>Q2</th>
<th>Q3</th>
<th>Q4</th>
<th>Final</th>
</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>";
foreach($show_explode as $value){
echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>
}
```